# Adjust sibling height to be the same as the shortest sibling

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a project preview for my portfolio where the left side of the row is an image and the right side is a container with project info.

Ideally, as the browser window shrinks, I'd like to maintain the aspect ratio of the image. This causes the image's height to shrink, so I'd like for the container on the right to shrink in height as well to match the image.

In the following CodePen, I show two implementations https://codepen.io/erikbue/pen/wmGewd

1. The image is set to object-fit: cover, meaning the aspect ratio
   is respected, but it's container shrinks, therefore cropping the
   image upon resize.

   ```
   .project-preview {
       flex-basis: 50%;
       flex-shrink: 0;
       overflow: hidden;
       position: relative;

       img {
           position: absolute;
           object-fit: cover;
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
       }
   }
   ```
2. I use the padding-top trick to maintain the
   image's aspect ratio, but as it resizes, the container on the
   right's height doesn't change and extends beyond the image height.

   ```
   .project-preview2 {
       flex-basis: 50%;
       flex-shrink: 0;
       overflow: hidden;
       position: relative;
       padding-top: 680px / 1160px * 100%;
       height: 0;

       img {
           position: absolute;
           top: 0;
           left: 0;
           width: 100%;
       }
   }
   ```

Is there a way to have the right container respect the height of the image as it resizes? You can see the issues best when you resize to about 1000px browser width.

Comment: You'll want to use flex for the project preview and details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947423/flexbox-equal-height-not-working

Comment: @PaigeMeinke that solution seems to only force the containers to increase in height, rather than shrink. I'm looking to make a container shrink to match the shortest sibling.